# Javascript For-loop time to clone thead

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I tried to create a fixed `thead` cloning an `thead` from another table.
To create all the `td` with the same width as the originals, I loop each `td` and copy the width.
I want to have the best performance because the table may have a lot of rows ( > 10000).
I look that the time spent by loop depends on rows in the original table; for example, with 100 rows take 10ms to loop 9 columns and 15000 rows take 350ms... why???
I iterate only the `thead` of the original table and it has always 1 row and fixed columns number...

The code:

```
var originTbl = document.querySelector("div.origin table.mytable");
var originTbl_Head = originTbl.querySelector("thead");
var cloneTbl = document.querySelector("div.cloned table.mytable");
var clone = originTbl_Head.cloneNode(true);
cloneTbl.appendChild(clone);
originTbl_Head.style.visibility = 'hidden';
var tds = cloneTbl.querySelectorAll('thead tr:first-child td');
var originTbl_Thead_Tr = originTbl.querySelectorAll("thead tr");
var td_list = originTbl_Thead_Tr[0].querySelectorAll('td');

console.time("loop");
for(i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    var td = td_list[i];
    var width = td.clientWidth;
    tds[i].style.width = width + 'px';
}
console.timeEnd('loop');
```

Comment: So.. "more rows takes longer to process"? Seems legit to me.. (processing time includes browser layout/rendering)

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: When you set and read `clientWidth` in the loop, you're forcing recalculation of the rendering values of the entire table on every round of the iteration. This means the width of the every single td in the table gets eventually being calculated, and that takes more time when calculating more rows.

Comment: See [layout thrashing](http://wilsonpage.co.uk/preventing-layout-thrashing/) for further explanations.

Comment: If you assigned width of  the original `<td>` , cloned copies of said originals will have the same width, so the loop isn't needed.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you! I’m reading the article but i don’t understand why if i read only the first row of the thead it recalculates the entire original table, including the body

Comment: That depends on the element, on the CSS and on the inline styles, on the implementation and who knows on what, but if the width is not defined, the widest cell in the column defines the width, that's why the whole table has to be iterated. Also, semantically correct is to use TH elements in the THEAD instead of TDs. Also this is more a theoretical question, the additional time is amazing small, considering the difference in the table sizes.

Comment: There are some interesting reading about calculating the column widths at [W3C Recommendations](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/tables.html#column-width). It looks like my "_every single td in the table gets eventually being calculated_" comment is what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

`why?`
Because when you do
`var originTbl = document.querySelector("div.origin table.mytable");`
It needs to trace all child element to the deepest child. So that explains why you can do `originTbl.querySelector("thead");`

To improve it, add id attribute to thead element and query the id directly with document.getElementById

Comment: Oh right sorry..thanks for noticing...i'll improve my answer soon